# Codeigniter, problems with extending classes

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following simplistic code:

// FILE: controllers/Top.php

```
class Top extends MY_Public_Controller {
        function __construct() {
   }
   public function Top() {
        echo 'Hello';
   }
 }
```

// FILE: application/core/MY_Public_Controller.php

```
 class MY_Public_Controller extends MY_Controller {
        function __construct() {
               parent::__construct();
        }
 }
```

// FILE:  application/core/MY_Controller.php

```
 class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
        function __construct() {
               parent::__construct();
        }
 }
```

And I get the following the following error:

```
 Fatal error: Class 'MY_Public_Controller' not found in 
 /var/www/example.com/public_html/application/controllers/Top.php on line 5
 A PHP Error was encountered
 Severity: Error
 Message: Class 'MY_Public_Controller' not found
 Filename: controllers/Top.php
 Line Number: 5
 Backtrace:
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of you create a new file (MY_Public_Controller.php) to create the class My_Public_Controller.

Insert this class inside the My_Controller.php file.

In that way the My_Controller.php file will be like:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
        function __construct() {
               parent::__construct();
        }
 }

class MY_Public_Controller extends MY_Controller {
        function __construct() {
               parent::__construct();
        }
 }
```

**After I see another answer**

Or you can make something like #Hikmat Sijapati said, but instead of you put the require_once, inside the My_Controller.php. Try to put it in the My_Public_Controller.php using 'My_Controller.php' as parameter. Something like that:

My_Public_Controller.php:

```
include_once('My_Controller.php');
class MY_Public_Controller extends MY_Controller {
        function __construct() {
               parent::__construct();
        }
 }
```

I have not tried it that way, but I think it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this...

1. You can create any number of controller but create controller's must be included in the controller that extends `CI_Controller`.As Below:
2. Controller's Name and function Name Keep  different (Good Way)

MY_Controller:`application/core/MY_Controller.php`

```
 class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
        function __construct() {
               parent::__construct();
        }
include_once('MY_Public_Controller.php');// include here
 }
```

MY_Public_Controller: `application/core/MY_Public_Controller.php`

```
class MY_Public_Controller extends MY_Controller {
        function __construct() {
               parent::__construct();
        }
 }
```

And Top: `application/Top.php`

```
class Top extends MY_Public_Controller {
        function __construct() {
   }
   public function index() {  //function name must be different than controller's name
        echo 'Hello';
   }
 }
```

Comment: None of the above 2 solutions work as presented.  Same error.

Comment: I tried it like this and it still doesn't work.  https://snag.gy/S0qPYR.jpg

Comment: also include your private and admin controllers.

Comment: let's get this working first.

MY_Controller -> MY_Public_Controller -> Top

Comment: are you using MX controller for HMVC?